# XSD: define complex element with attribute and other child elements

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I want to define an element like this:

```
<A id='1'>
  <name>jack</name>
</A>
```

With this below I could define attribute `id` of element A:

```
<xs:complexType name="A">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="id"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Actually it's not correct, the XSD above defines an element `<A id="1">hi</A>`. I don't know how to discard the base attribute of `<xs:extension>` element.

And with the XSD below I could define the inside element `<name>`:

```
<xs:element name = "A">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>

            <xs:element name = "name" type="xs:string"/>

        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Could I combine this two together like this below? I could not get the syntax correct.

```
    <xs:element name = "A">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name = "name" type="xs:string"/>                       
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
          <xs:extension>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="id"/>
          </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:element>
```

Answer (score 3):

Nothing in your XML or stated constraints indicates `xs:extension` is required here.

**The following simple XSD,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="A">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**will validate your XML,**

```
<A id='1'>
  <name>jack</name>
</A>
```

**as requested.**

Comment: One more important thing to note is `xs:attribute` **must** come after `xs:sequence` inside `xs:complexType`